# How to use committed usage discount instance in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need GKE node pool with 5 instance 2vcpu and 8GB ram, do I need to create 5 CUD instance and seperately, will it be recognized by GKE cluster while creation.

what about boot disk and OS image for committed usage instance, its not asking for it which creation CUD in compute engine.

Answer (score 0):

When you commit (in the compute engine page -> Commited Used Discount), you purchase CPU and Memory in a region for 1 or 3 years. If you haven't local SSD or GPU, it's the easiest!!

In you case, you simply have to select the region that you want, to select the CPU generation (N1, N2,...) and set 10 vCPU and 40Gb of memory.

That's all. If your GKE node pool is in the same region and uses the same CPU generation, your discount will be automatically enforced.

Disks and OS Images aren't take into account in the CUD.